# Android Studio: My app is restarting but there are no errors

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a strange question for u all can someone tell me what is wrong with my code? there are no errors but still not opening. its restarting.

I think the main problem is my java code.

Here it is(this is the shorter version) :

```
public class EasyLvl1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int presCounter = 0;
    private int maxPresCounter = 5;
    private String[] keys = {"I", "N", "P", "U", "T","G","A"};
    private String textAnswer = "INPUT";
    TextView Lvl1TextScreen, Lvl1Question,Lvl1Title;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_easy_lvl1);

        keys = shuffleArray(keys);

        for (String key : keys) {
            addView(((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutParent)), key, ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)));
        }

        maxPresCounter = 5;
    }


    private String[] shuffleArray(String[] ar) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
            String a = ar[index];
            ar[index] = ar[i];
            ar[i] = a;
        }
        return ar;
```

Comment: try using the No Filter, Verbose option in Logcat.

Comment: can you add the `addView` function? and please add logcat screenshot with error filter instead of verbose